# Emberjs - Pass an object from the view to controller

Tags: ember.js

I am using a radialProgress as a jQuery plugins (homemade), and I need to implement it for ember but I have some issue to do that.

Quick explanation for the plugins :

```
var chart = $(yourElement).pieChart(options); // initialise the object to an element
chart.setCompleteProgress( complete, false ); // set how many item you have to complete the task
chart.incrementProgress(); // increment + 1 every time you call it
```

It's a very simple progress pie.

In my case my task are located inside my controller, but the chart as to select a dom element so I need to initialise it inside my view.
My task in the controller are called from the router from the setupController to reload the model over time.

Here is a small sample of what I would like to do :

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        var promise = controller.getModel();
        this._super(controller, promise);
    }
})

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    getModel: function() {
        // chart.setcompleteProgress();
        // A lot of code are here to get some data
        // chart.incrementProgress();
        return newModel;
    }
})

App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        var chart = $(element).pieChart(opts);
    }
})
```

I don't know how to pass the chart object from the view to the controller to be able to have access to my plugin function.

Comment: View already has access to the controller. Inside the controller you can use this.get(controller). Something like this should work, this.set('controller.chart', chart);

Comment: yes, but the thing is that the chart is undefined when my controller function is called from the router...

Comment: Ur flow of control seems a bit off to me. If you just want to update ur chart once the model is loaded or changed, create an observer to the model in the view, and rerender the chart plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Che chart won't be inserted into the DOM until the `didInsertElement` therefore you can't attempt to manipulate it in the `route` during `setupController` etc.  I'd suggest creating a method in the controller `setupChart` and calling that on `didInsertElement`.

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    prepPieChart: function() {
        var chart = $(element).pieChart(opts);
        this.get('controller').setupPieChart(chart);
    }.on('didInsertElement')
})

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    setupPieChart: function(chart) {
       chart.setcompleteProgress();
        // A lot of code are here to get some data
       chart.incrementProgress();
    }
})
```

All that being said, maybe it belongs in the view, but I'm not sure of what you're completely doing.

Comment: I managed to make it work putting it directly inside the `didInsertElement` and `this.set('controller.chart', chart);`. it's working well like this !